# Differentiate parts of generic union in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to implement following function

```
const foo = <S>(newState: S | ((prevState: S) => S)) => {...}
```

so it takes either new state of type `S` or a function producing new state from the old state.

How can I differentiate between those options in the implementation? I assume `typeof newState === 'function'` won't work as `S` can be a function just as well.

I'm using typescript but probably the solution would have more to do with JS then TS.

Comment: It's technically impossible; if I call `foo((s: string) => s.toUpperCase())`, then `S` can be either `string` or `(s: string)=>string`, since the type `(s: string)=>string` matches both `string | ((s: string)=>string)` and the bizarre-but-possible `((s: string) => string) | ((p: (s: string) => string) => ((s: string) => string))`.  You'll have to pick some heuristic, like "`S` won't be a function" to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz thank you, I expected such answer but hoped it's not true. I would be glad to accept it as an answer. This also means React.useState is inherently incorrect as such restriction is not present there yet the signature is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can use `typeof` to solve your problem, like:

```
if(typeof newState === 'function') {
    newState();
} else {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: yes, but what if my `S` is also a function? So effectively I can have `function X` or `a function that takes function X and produces new function X`. This check won't help there, right?

Comment: How could that happen? Isn't S a class or an interface?

Comment: Why would it be? `S` can be anything. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8BlAfACgB4BcMGAlCljAN4BQMMokIANgKYB0TIA5jlAJ4AHFiDgw8JagF9q1BCBw4yyCgCIAEiz4qSQA